# Javascript onmousedown toggleDiv (toggle 2 divs?)

Tags: javascript, php

So I am really new to javascript, I wouldn't know a line of it if my life depended on it. Somehow I managed to get this to work....

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onmousedown="toggleDiv(' , $message['id'] , ');">
```

Problem is I need 2 divs to toggle. I thought since they both had the same ID it would toggle them both but it does not. I changed the second one to have "dateline" after the message ID. Not sure how to make this work and would really appreciate a hand :).

I do not wish to use jQuery.

Was asked for this:

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleDiv(divid){
                if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == \'none\'){
                    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = \'block\';
                    document.pageLoading.TCallLabel(\'/\',\'restart_function\');
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = \'none\';
                }
            }
    </script>';
```

Comment: Why you don't call the toggle twice? `onmousedown="toggleDiv(id1); toggleDiv(id2);"`

Comment: Please share `toggleDiv`'s function code. @Ahmad please don't. It's bad enough as it is.

Comment: I edited the post cause I don't really understand how to put it in a comment, is that what you wanted? :)

Comment: Why two div have the same id? you can set different id to them and call the function twice as I mentioned in previous comment

Comment: IDs must be unique in the page, if 2 tags share the same id, the behaviour of the page is unpredictable accross browsers.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't thinking.

Comment: I tried the toggle twice thing @Ahmad but it isn't working for me. They both have different IDs. Console says it's an uncaught illegal syntax error.

Comment: then its a syntax error, you should modify your code maybe something is written wrong or somthing is missed

Comment: @Ahmad it's saying some code I don't recognise is the issue...

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=C48a4tkz

Comment: I suggest you to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which makes anything easier, pure javascripit is hard to program.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same id on two HTML elements. If you need to have a shared selector, you should use a class. Then your script becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleDiv(divClass){
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(divClass);
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                if(divs[i].style.display == 'none'){
                    divs[i].style.display = 'block';
                    // Not sure what this is doing, you may want to move it outside of the loop
                    document.pageLoading.TCallLabel('/','restart_function');
                }else{
                    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: That's not working for me, now it's not toggling either div :(

Comment: Did you change your div output to use a class instead of ids?

Comment: Yes, I changed them to both have classes, one was called messageid_dateline and the other messageid_hiddenquickbuttons which I also updated the names of in the original. :)

Maybe I didn't escape it right?

Comment: I just tested this code without the part about `document.pageLoading.TCallLabel()` and it correctly hides/shows the elements that have that class. Can you put your html output in a pastebin?

Comment: It's a bit awful, sorry.
http://pastebin.com/bqpixaiz
http://pastebin.com/VNdrxCNs

Comment: It looks like you are missing quotes around your class names i.e. current output: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onmousedown="toggleDiv(11990_dateline2); toggleDiv(11990_hiddenquickbuttons);">` needed output: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onmousedown="toggleDiv('11990_dateline2'); toggleDiv('11990_hiddenquickbuttons');">`

Comment: That got it!! But I have to click twice to see both parts. Once to see the first div and again to see the second. Was that intentional? I wanted them to show at the same time :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65468/discussion-between-rdubya-and-jade-elizabeth).